# Swapping input field placeholder text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try as following jquery code, but it doesn't work true, how can fix it?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pjqcf/

```
<input type="text" value="Some descriptive text...">​

$('input[type=text]').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('defaultValue')) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
$('input[type=text]').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('defaultValue'));
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't set "defaultValue" attribute of your input. Set "defaultValue" to "Some descriptive text.." and it should work

```
<input type="text" value="Some descriptive text..." defaultValue="Some descriptive text...">​
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine after adding defaultValue to your markup. See below change,

```
<input type="text" 
    value="Some descriptive text..." 
    defaultValue="Some descriptive text...">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/pjqcf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

change "defaultValue" to "value". Or add defaultValue  attribute to your input

Comment: I change "defaultValue" to "value" but it doesn't work true, see: http://jsfiddle.net/pjqcf/2/

Comment: yes, it does not work, sorry. so you can to add defaulValue attr to your input or use jQuery.data(), in case you do want to pass validation. Or may be smth else, it's rather trivial thing